# How do I move a jPlayer playlist to another position on the page?

Tags: jquery, css, position, jplayer, playlist

In default mode the jPlayer playlist is displayed below the jPlayer controls.  I would like to move it to another position on the page (on the right of the page in a 2 column layout with the jPlayer controls/poster on the left), but when I move the code that generates the playlist to another place on the page, i.e.

```
<div class="jp-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered list -->
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Nothing shows in the playlist.  So it would seem that this code needs to be included within the jp_container_1 div.  If so, how can I display the playlist on the right of my page?

**Full markup for jPlayer is below:**

```
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-270p">
            <div class="jp-type-playlist">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div class="jp-gui">
                    <div class="jp-video-play">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-interface">
                        <div class="jp-progress">
                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                        <div class="jp-title">
                            <ul>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-controls-holder">
                            <ul class="jp-controls">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="jp-toggles">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="shuffle">shuffle</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="shuffle off">shuffle off</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered list -->
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <span>Update Required</span>
                    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: position: absolute them

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer is targeting `jp_container_1` to render the player and playlist. You have a couple of options:

1. Rearrange the position of the elements within `jp_container_1` with CSS positioning.
2. Change jPlayer's target element for the the playlist in `add-on/jplayer-playlist.js`

For jPlayer 2.2.0, jplayer-playlist.js > line 39:

```
this.cssSelector.playlist = this.cssSelector.cssSelectorAncestor + " .jp-playlist";
```

Change to:

```
this.cssSelector.playlist = this.cssSelector + " .jp-playlist";
```

If you do this, it will mess up multi-instance support for jPlayer, meaning you will only be able to have one instance of the player with a playlist per page.